# Problem with HTML table rendering in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox

The table renders differently in Firefox from IE8/Chrome.

The website is here: http://nordschleife.metaforix.net/118/118/index.php/panasonic.html?id=5&___store=uk&___from_store=default

I'd prefer the looks & feel of the table under IE8/Chrome, as the lines are light gray instead of completely black.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: The table lines are a light-gray to me on FF3

Comment: I'm using 3.0.10 with both Windows 7 & Ubuntu, and both show black lines

Answer (score 2):

you need to give the TD element the light gray border color in the CSS information.

For example

```
table tr td {border:1px solid #DDD; }
```